# How to escape apostrophe in php variable for select query

Tags: php, mysql, string, mysqli, escaping

I have tried escaping the query string and the `$variable` containing the apostrophe using the mysqli_real_escape_string the variable value is coming form the database. I am getting the following error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Shamrock Rovers%\' AND away_team like \'St Patrick's Athletic%\'' at line 1

The apostrophe is not getting escaped by the quotes around the comparison values is.

Here is the query as it appears in the PHP file:

```
    $homeTeam = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'homeTeam', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $homePlayers = "select * from players where team_name like $homeTeam";
    $homePlayers = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $homePlayers);
    $homePlayersResult = mysqli_query($dbc, $homePlayers);
```

And `echo`ed out to the browser:

```
    select * from players where team_name like Shamrock Rovers
```

I have tried it a number of different ways with no variation in results i feel i am overlooking something simple. 
Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

***Updated Code***

```
$homeTeam = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'homeTeam', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);          
$homeTeam = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $homeTeam);
echo "<br>".$homeTeam."<br>";
$homePlayers = "select * from players where team_name like '$homeTeam%'";

$homePlayersResult = mysqli_query($dbc, $homePlayers);
```

This Script recieves 3 parameters from a processing script

```
header("location: ../scorer.php?gameWeek=$gameWeek&homeTeam=$homeTeam&awayTeam=$awayTeam");
```

outputs
     select * from players where team_name like 'St Patrick's Athletic%'

**Edit 2**

after entering the query in to mysql command window nothing happens when i submit the query once but when i enter it again i get the following err.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
like $homeTeam";
```

you need to quote that variable.

```
like '$homeTeam'";
```

or

```
like '$homeTeam%'";
```

since this is a string, as per your `like Shamrock Rovers`

However I don't know why you're using

```
$homePlayers = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $homePlayers);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

while escaping your query: (?)

```
$homePlayers = "select * from players where team_name like $homeTeam";
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You probably meant to use:

```
$homePlayers = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $homeTeam);
```

---

- Consider using parametrized queries such as [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) instead.

---

**Edit:** (test)

This is what I used to successfully query a test table of mine, being "users".

```
<?php

$DB_HOST = 'xxx';
$DB_USER = 'xxx';
$DB_PASS = 'xxx';
$DB_NAME = 'xxx';

$Link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($Link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $Link->connect_error . ']');
}

$_GET['homeTeam'] = "St Patrick's Athletic";

$username = $_GET['homeTeam'];

$homeTeam = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'homeTeam', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$homePlayers = mysqli_real_escape_string($Link, $homeTeam);
$homePlayers = "select * from users where username like '$homeTeam%'";
$homePlayersResult = mysqli_query($Link, $homePlayers);

echo "Names found like: " . $username;

echo "<br>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($homePlayersResult)){

echo $row['username'];

echo "<br>";

echo "<a href=\"{$row['my_row']}\">".$row['my_row']."</a>";

echo "<br>";

}
```

- Plus, make sure that your column is indeed VARCHAR and its length long enough and that your input is a "text type".

**Sidenote:**

You don't need this which will break your query:

```
$homeTeam = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'homeTeam', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

since you're already using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize your input.

Something that we've discussed during our chat which was resolved, yet I did already mention the above before chatting which was the solution after all.

Comment: I don't like seeing mysqli_real_escape_string anyway, I'd rather people just use query bindings, but that's just my opinion

Comment: @Zarathuztra Indeed; Parametrized is a much better method which was added to my answer.

Comment: this did fix the problem for queries without parameters that contained special characters but ones with special return no error but no result. will update question

Comment: @Lonergan6275 you should have "added" to your question instead of overwriting your original post and marked as an "edit" under it. Please edit it to be just that, otherwise people will see your question and my answer and say/ask themselves "Why the answer?"

Comment: well i cant seem to rollback the revission. there is a dropdawn at the top but nothing happerns when i change it

Comment: @Lonergan6275 I've done a rollback. Now, I've tested your code along with my fixes and was successful. I will add an example piece of code under my answer in a few minutes. However, I don't know where you're getting your GET from, so I'll just post an example. Give me a few minutes and I'll post it under my answer near the bottom.

Comment: @Lonergan6275 Reload my answer under **Edit** (test). that's what I used to test this with. Plus, are you using this with a form?

Comment: the apostrophe is still tripping it up

Comment: @Lonergan6275 from the looks of your screen capture, you're not wrapping your `St Patrick's Athletic` with regular single quotes `'` but as curly quotes. Why are you entering that in your command window and posting your code as running under a PHP environment? Can you post your full code as to how you are entering `St Patrick's Athletic` into your form? Plus, that's **if** you're using a form and does your form method correspond to GET and not POST? it's unclear at this point as to how this is being used.

Comment: i just coppied the echo ed query from the browser to the cmd line to test if it worked and it did if i manually escape the apostrophe. im not using a form but i am getting it from a url var coming from a processing script

Comment: @Lonergan6275 I need to know exactly how you're passing that URL from your processing script. I am doing my best to help you out, but there are a lot of unknowns here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76246/discussion-between-lonergan6275-and-fred-ii).

Comment: Needed a duplicate today and couldn't use this page because prepared statement wasn't used.